Holomorphic and bounded implies uniform continuity
I'm working on the following Qualifying Exam problem:

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be the upper half plane, and let $f: \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic and bounded. For a given $r> 0$, let $\mathbb{H}_r = \{z \in \mathbb{H} \mid \Im (z) \geq r \}$. Prove that for any $r > 0$, the restriction $$ f\mid _{\mathbb{H}_r}: \mathbb{H}_r \to \mathbb{C} $$ is uniformly continuous.

I was given a hint to use the principle that "bounded and analytic" gives pass to bounded first derivative, which implies uniform continuity, but I am not sure of how to formalize:
We can easily get bounded derivative using the Cauchy estimates for $f'$, is it true that this implies uniform continuity? This was asked before, but left unanswered and I'm a bit confused.

If $f'$ is bounded then surely it is Lipschitz.
